# Displaying a search term in search field after submit

Tags: html

Here is my code, I'm using HTML5 for my search logic:

```
<form style="padding-top: 15px; margin-bottom:-15px" onsubmit="location.href='/search/' + document.getElementById('userInput').value; return false;" />
    <input id="userInput" style="width:150px; padding: 5px; margin: 0 5px; font-size: 90%;" type="text" value="" onclick="this.value=''" />
    <input style="width:80px; height: 25px; font-size: 90%;" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

How would I display the search value typed by the user in the field after submit?  I feel like there is a HTML5 tag - but uncertain...

Comment: How are you retrieving the search variable from the url? Are you using any server-side script?

Answer (score 0):

There is no HTML5 tag that means "remember what was typed in here prior to submitting the form" -- that isn't the role of an HTML element.

After the form submits, you're on a new page. You'll either be redirecting, or rendering a page. So, to display the search term in the form, you'll need to place the term in the `value` attribute of the search field as you render the results page, whatever method you use to do so.

I'm not sure what server-side technology you're using, so I can't be very specific, but generally:

`<input ... value="[IF length($searchValue) > 0 THEN print $searchValue]" ... />`

Also, you are using an inline `onclick` event to set the value of the field to an empty string -- even if you successfully carry the value through, as soon as the user focuses on the input the carried value would be cleared; you might want to reconsider that bit of javascript.